# Error in Code - dbCommand.ExecuteReader()

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Can anyone tell me How do I solve this error.
Error: NullReferenceException was Unhandled - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Line:  Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
Database: MS Access
IDE: VB 2010 Express

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System


Public Class Form1       
Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection        
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand       
Dim strInsert As String       
Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter        
Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source =atg.mdb"

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectString) 'here I use the new keyword to initialize connection  
 dbConnection.Open()
 Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT XX FROM ABC", dbConnection) ' initialize command and pass query and open connection to its constructor  
 Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader() 'ERROR IS HERE
 Do While (reader.Read()) ' loop here until reader finish reading and add every row to the list box  
        ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.Item("ABC"))             
        ListBox1.EndUpdate()
    Loop
    reader.Close()
    dbConnection.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you find dbCommand in dbCommand.ExecuteReader() statement.Use command.ExecuteReader() instead .

You didn't initiate your dbCommand.You just Decalared it.What you did is creating another variable called command and initiated it.So try with this

Answer (score -1):

Part of the programma:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'MajDgv()
        Module1.connect()
        Me.fillcombo()
End Sub
Sub fillcombo()

        strsql = "select from Liste des responsables"
        Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim acsdr As OleDbDataReader
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader()""THE PROBLEM IS HERRE he sayed that ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."""""""
        While (acsdr.Read())
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(acsdr("Nom"))

        End While
        acscmd.Dispose()
        acsdr.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I create a Module:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public acsconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public acsdr As OleDbDataReader
    Public strsql As String
    Sub connect()
        acsconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=|datadirectory|\Base1.accdb;"
        acsconn.Open()
    End Sub
End Module
```